libavcodec: usage of max_samples while decoding?
After opening a codec for decoding audio (wav 16 bit signed, 2 channels),
I set the AVCodecContext::max_samples to the following:
buf->bytes_per_sample = av_get_bytes_per_sample(codec_ctx->sample_fmt); // returns 2
codec_ctx->max_samples = (buf->buffer_size_in_bytes) / (buf->bytes_per_sample * codec_ctx->ch_layout.nb_channels); // 512

The codec_ctx->sample_fmt is set to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16 and the channel count is 2.
With buf->buffer_size_in_bytes of 2048, the theoretical maximum sample count should be 512.
However, when I call avcodec_send_packet in the following manner:
    int response = av_read_frame(buf->format_ctx,buf->packet);
    if(response >= 0 ) {
        int ret;
        do {
            ret = avcodec_send_packet(buf->codec_ctx, buf->packet);
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(buf->codec_ctx,buf->frame);
        } while (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN));

I receive the following error:

[pcm_s16le @ 0000029AA8907C00] samples per frame 1024, exceeds max_samples 512
[pcm_s16le @ 0000029AA8907C00] get_buffer() failed

max_samples seems to be ignored because it tries to get 1024 samples?
What I do not understand is why it does not work with a buffer size of 4096 either:

[pcm_s16le @ 000002138368E840] samples per frame 1024, exceeds max_samples 1024
[pcm_s16le @ 000002138368E840] get_buffer() failed

It only starts to work with a buffer size of 8192, anything below that throws this error.
I double checked the content of codec_ctx and max_samples is the specified value before, during and after av_read_frame and avcodec_receive_frame
